# Define Gitlab environment

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab repository where I have different variables assigned to different environments. I have a pipeline for this repository which I would like to be deployed to those different environments.

I don't want to code the environment directly in my code so I would like to choose the environment manually as the first stage of my pipeline so that the pipeline only use those variables assigned to the chosen environment since then.

Is this possible in gitlab? Has it any sense?

Comment: This is the best shot at it: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#specifying-variables-when-running-manual-jobs

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use [dynamic child-pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/parent_child_pipelines.html#dynamic-child-pipelines) to create a "blank" template of your deployments that will be serialized using your variables during your main pipeline. This way you could have cleanly separated jobs for each environnements.

I hope this help or at least gives some clues about the right way to do it, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

We use the commit branch name for which the pipeline is running for to declare our environments.

```
  environment:
    name: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

You can see the predefined GitLab variables like the above used [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)

If you want to have further control to modify this variable during manual pipeline as you have asked in the question, GitLab provides that functionality, you can check it out [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#specifying-variables-when-running-manual-jobs)

Answer (score 0):

I do not this that you can re-use variable defined or specified for one stage in another one. One of the key things of ci job is to be as much repeatable as possible, so jobs from the upcoming stages can't inherit variables from the previous one.

In my experience there are always some small differences between environments, so for me it make sense to almost copy/paste jobs definitions for different envs.